# Difference Between Network and Server Applications

Tags: node.js, servlets, networking, web-applications

Is there a difference between a network and server application? For instance, node.js boasts the ability to "build fast, scalable network applications". How is this any different than writing a servlet with PHP? Or are they one and the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server application run on server and clients use some network protocols to connect and make some operation over it so it means every server application is a network application too. But with this sentence

> build fast, scalable network applications

I guess they try to emphasize node.js has a lot of ability to do operation over network,IO and database operation with its libraries.

There are 3 different things asked at this question

- Node.js can be used for server programming like servlet. You can write javascript to developed a asynchronous server with the help of node.js libraries. You use javascript for client(jquery) and server(node.js) side.
- You developed a server use of java programming language and help of servlet libraries. Also you can use java at both side client and server side programming.
- Php is a server side scripting language, at server side there is php interpreter, php code converts to html. But server side is Apache HTTP server and CGI. Actually i am not expert PHP server side things.

Comment: "Php is a scripting language you can use php at client side only", PHP is a server-side language not a client-side language?

Comment: @Eric Sorry for wrong information, you are right. I edit my post.